# Macro to search list JDE ERP

Tags: iseries

I have a list of Part numbers in a txt file.  I need to get the matching Inventory number for each from our JDE database. Is it possible to build a macro in I-Series to search a JDE database for matches from a text file?

Comment: Don't think you're going to get much JD Edwards help here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is this not the appropriate stack for this?